# vue.js register webcomponent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, web-component, stenciljs

I am using vue.js and created a webcomponent with stencil.js. I don't want to publish the webcomponent to npm, which is why I simply include it in the src/assets directory in my vue project.

However I get the error

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <my-component> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option. 
    found in ---> 
        <App> at src/app.vue
            <Root>
```

It works without problems with another component I already have in the assets directory.

It also doesn't help to use

```
Vue.config.ignoredElements = ['my-component'];
```

since the component is still empty when I run it locally.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're including the web component locally, you can use @vue/web-component-wrapper:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import wrap from '@vue/web-component-wrapper'

const Component = {
  // any component options
}

const CustomElement = wrap(Vue, Component)

window.customElements.define('my-element', CustomElement)
```

Comment: This seems more for turning a vue component into a web component. What if we have a web component we want to use in vue?

Answer (score 0):

just in case, for me that was a version issue:

my components were defined like that:

```
export default class Foo extends ScopedElementsMixin(LitElement) {
   ...
}
```

And in the vue I did

```
customElements.define('foo', Foo);
```

I started received that error when I updated scoped-elements `1.x.x` -> `2.x.x`.

So when **I put everything back to `1.x.x`** the error just gone.